# How to create std::map with key value random

Tags: c++, dictionary, random

I am testing speed of writing a std::map(std::string, std::string) to file in hard disk (using serialization of Boost). So I need create a map with a lot of element in map. I have a problem when create random keys for map. Here is my code to generate map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

string randomString(int len) {
    srand(time(0));
    string str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int pos;
    while (str.size() != len) {
        pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
        str.erase(pos, 1);
    }
    return str;
}

void save() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
    string key;
    string value;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        myMap[randomString(20)] = randomString(20);
    }

    cout << "Map size: " << myMap.size() << endl;

    for (map<string, string>::iterator ii = myMap.begin(); ii != myMap.end(); ++ii) {
        cout << (*ii).first << ": " << (*ii).second << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    save();
    return 0;
}
```

In for loop, the keys are the same so my map has only one element. What is wrong with code? Please help me and do you have different way to create map with random elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `srand` every time you call `randomString`, and since the time returned by the `time` function only have second resolution, if you call `randomString` multiple times within the same second, all those calls will set the same seed leading to you having the same "random" sequence.

Call `srand` only *once*, at the beginning of the program.